# Should I access these attributes directly or rather use proxy methods?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, encapsulation, proxy-classes

My client API encapsulates connections to the server in a class `ServerConnection` that stores an `asyncio.StreamReader/-Writer` pair. (For simplicity, I will not use `yield from` or any other async technique in the code below because it doesn't matter for my question.)

Now, I wonder whether it's better to expose both streams as part of `ServerConnection`'s public interface than to introduce read()/write() methods to `ServerConnection` which forward calls to the respective stream's methods. Example:

```
class ServerConnection:
    def __init__(self, reader, writer):
        self.reader = reader
        self.writer = writer
```

vs.

```
class ServerConnection:
    def __init__(self, reader, writer):
        self._reader = reader
        self._writer = writer

    def read(self, size):
        return self._reader.read(size)

    def readline(self):
        return self._reader.readline()

    def write(self, data):
        return self._writer.write(data)

    def close(self):
        return self._writer.close()

    # …further proxy methods…
```

Pros/cons that I'm aware of so far:

**Pros:** `ServerConnection` is definitely some kind of bidirectional stream so it'd make sense to have it inherit from a `StreamRWPair`. Furthermore, it's much more convenient to use `server_conn.read()` than `server_conn.reader.read()`.

**Cons:** I would need to define a whole lot of proxy methods. (In my case, I actually use some kind of buffered reader that has additional methods like `peek()` and so on.) So I thought about creating a base class `StreamRWPair` similar to Python's `io.BufferedRWPair` that my `ServerConnection` can then inherit from. The Python implementation of the `io` module, however, says the following about `BufferedRWPair` in the comments:

> XXX The usefulness of this (compared to having two separate IO
>   objects) is questionable.

On top of that, my `ServerConnection` class has several other methods and I'm afraid that, by proxying, I will clutter its attribute namespace and make its usage less obvious.

Comment: I believe a sensible answer would depend on how the class is used. Could you edit the question adding some examples where the `ServerConnection` class is used?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, brandizzi. I actually planned to use the above pattern at different places in my code (i.e. with several classes) because I need to deal with all kinds of streams, so I had a hard time trying to find representative examples. Thanks to your question, I realized that this was because my requirements differed depending on the context. Keeping this in mind, I decided to use a `StreamRWPair` class in cases where I need only the stream functionality but stick with the reader/writer separation where the focus of the class / the API actually lies on other functionality.